# :Store SQL Data in a php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to add data from mySQL to an array in a php script. However, the script is set to execute once a day automatically, and the array would vary in size. Is there a way to make a php array that varies in size depending on the amount a data acquired from mySQL?

Update:
So far this is what I have (after removing all the confidential info, of course)

```
$var1 = array();
$var2 = array();

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
else
{
    echo "Connected successfully";
}
echo "\r\n";
//select data from
$sql = //SQL File here
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $var1 = $row[Row 1];
    $var2 = $row[Row 2];
}

?>
```

Comment: Any array derived from the query would be the size of the results from the query.

Comment: Arrays are dynamic. They are whatever size the data set is. Please look up PHP arrays http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and try yourself before posting this question. Then if you have some code that is not working, post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you grab your info, you can add each line from the MySQL query to an array as you loop through results.

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){
    $new_array[] = $row;
}
```